# How to disable/enable the entire row in table with help of enable/disable buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my table I have two buttons **Enable** and **Disable**. In the table I want to disable/enable the entire row with the help of these buttons. At first the Disable button must be Active while Enable button is disabled. When I click on Disable button the entire row should get disabled and the Enable button must get active while Disable button gets disabled. How to do it in angularJS. Help needed.

```
<table style="border:1px solid;">
<tr>
  <td>one</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>three</td>
  <td>
    <button>ENABLE</button><br/>
    <button>DISABLE</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/vtkj1cug/](https://jsfiddle.net/vtkj1cug/1/)

Comment: First clarify what you want to enable/disable. This must be applied on form-controls only.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am expecting you know how `ng-repeat` works this is how its done:

```
// HTML
<tr ng-repeat="item of items"
    ng-click="rowClicked(item)"
    class="{{item.enabled ? 'row-enabled': ''}}">
  <td>Content 1</td>
  <td>Content 2</td>
  <td>Content 3</td>
  <td>Content 4</td>
  <td>Content 5</td>
  <td>
    <button ng-if="!item.enabled"
            ng-click="item.enabled = true">
      ENABLE
    </button>
    <button ng-if="item.enabled"
            ng-click="item.enabled = false">
      DISABLE
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>

//JS
$scope.rowClicked = function(item)
{
  if (!item.enabled)
  {
    // HEY ROW IS DISABLED YOU CAN'T PASS
    return;
  }

  // stuff
}
```

UPDATED:

since the scope of your question changed here is an update for your needs

```
// HTML
<tr ng-click="rowClicked()"
    class="{{!rowEnabled ? 'disabled': ''}}">
  <td>Content 1</td>
  <td>Content 2</td>
  <td>Content 3</td>
  <td>Content 4</td>
  <td>Content 5</td>
  <td>
    <button ng-disabled="!rowEnabled"
            ng-click="rowEnabled = true">
      ENABLE
    </button>
    <button ng-disabled="rowEnabled"
            ng-click="rowEnabled = false">
      DISABLE
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>

//JS
$scope.rowEnabled = false; // put it somewhere in your declaration area.

$scope.rowClicked = function()
{
  if (!$scope.rowEnabled)
  {
    // HEY ROW IS DISABLED YOU CAN'T PASS
    return;
  }

  // stuff
}
```

NOTE: there is no `disabled` attribute for table elements, it is only applied to input elements. So if you want to have a disabled look you need to create it yourself using CSS like:

```
tr.disabled {
   // some styles to make your element disabled
   cursor: default;
}
```

[working angularjs example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33854/)
hope that helps

Comment: You can still make it work by simply removing the ng-repeat, anyways i'll update the answer

Comment: fine. Can you check that fiddle link.

Comment: I checked your linked and created the code above on how it is done in angular, I created an update though this ain't javascript implementation but it will give you an idea https://jsfiddle.net/vtkj1cug/2/. I will create fiddle example shortly

Comment: @MusheerAiman working angularjs example http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33854/

Answer (score 0):

You can only enable and disable form elements, if you want to disable a table row you most likly are looking for css styling,

On form elements you can use

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-disable="[Enabled true false var]"> {{enable}} </md-button>
<md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-disable="![Enabled true false var]"> {{disable}} </md-button>
```

[ng-disable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

On the table row you can add an [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to style the form element

```
<tr ng-class="{'enabled-row': [Enabled true false var], 'disabled-row': ![Enabled true false var]}">
```